# Multiple DB usage with Rails 6.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, multiple-databases

Well, I have been reading a lot about this online but I could not solve the problem I face with.

What I want is being able to fetch and store data from multiple DB's from one Rails project. But the problem is, when I create another model for another DB such like user_db_1.rb and user_db_2.rb, when `establish_connection` method under user_db_2.rb is triggered, all my project starts fetching data from db_2. I want all my models to run on primary database except I set something custom to fetch and save data from db_2.

What is the correct way of implementing this on Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails version 6.x supports reading and updating records from/to multiple databases.

Following this, [link](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html) will be useful

We have to explicitly specify to which database needed to be used on model level.

```
class PrimaryModel < ApplicationRecord
  connects_to database: { 
    writing: :primary_db, 
    reading: :secondary_db 
  }
end
```

The respective database configuration, `database.yml` would be

```
production:
  primary_db:
    database: prima_database
    username: root
    password: <%= ENV['ROOT_PASSWORD'] %>
    adapter: mysql2
  secondary_db:
    database: sec_database
    username: root
    password: <%= ENV['ROOT_READONLY_PASSWORD'] %>
    adapter: mysql2
    replica: false
```

Comment: Well, I did the exact same thing as you described but the problem is, I don't want to write to db1 and read to db2 I want to use db1 on some models and db2 on some models. So, when I run establish_connection(:db2) whole project connects to db2 and it brokes all my logic as you can understand.

Comment: use `connects_to database: {reading: primary_db, writing: primary_db}` in the model level, and also go through the documentation given in the answer It shows different solutions for your problem!!